# Borders all the same size around the links in CSS

Tags: html, css

Thanks for taking the time to read my comment. I'm a newbie to this site so i hope i do everything in the right manner. I got a college assignment this week for web development and have it all finished bar one part. I want all the borders to be the same size rather than just the size of each text section. I have all the a visited, hovered and that all ready to go. its just making all the rectangles the same size.
Any Feedback would be greatly appreciated.

i have my links set up as follows:

HTML

```
    <div id="SideNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="button">Home    </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Current Issue     </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Back Issues       </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Articles          </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Editorial Policy  </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Submissions       </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">MA CAA            </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Links             </a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Contact US        </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #SideNav{
     float: left;
     width:20%;
    }

    #SideNav ul{
     list-style:none;       
    }

        .button { 

    border: 0.1em inset #000000;
    padding: .25em  .125em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    clear:both;  
}
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi there im not using any javascript.

Comment: Yes, I know. Jsfiddle make easier to understand your problem and solve it. Please read [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/jsfiddle-an-online-playground-for-your-javascript-html-css/)

Comment: Thank you. I will read this now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display:block;`, and another tweaks for perfection.

**CSS**

```
 #SideNav {
     float: left;
     width:30%;
 }
 #SideNav ul {
     list-style:none;
     display:block;
 }
 .button {
     display: block;
     border: solid 1px #ccc;
     padding: .25em .125em;
     color: #ffffff;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
     font-size: 1em;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration:none;
     color: #000;
     border-top:none;
 }
 li:first-child {
     border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="SideNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="button">Home    </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Current Issue     </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Back Issues       </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Articles          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Editorial Policy  </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Submissions       </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">MA CAA            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Links             </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="button">Contact US        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2r1Ly00t/1/)**

Comment: thats perfect mate. I have still inserted my line breaks however to give a space between each link

Comment: No...is´t not good practice, instead give `margin-bottom` or give `padding` to `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. Text was not clear(`changed Color to black`).
2. `<br> tag`: you do not need to use it you can position any element in a new line by css(`display: block;`). and etc

However, I fixed your problem.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anr9twr9/)